# Android Basics in Kotlin: confused by Introduction to Debugging

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging

I have a very basic question. I'm following through the development guide **codelabs** in the suggested order, and failing at "Intro To Debugging" section 6: "Record a Running App". I find the explanation very confusing because rather minimal for a beginner.

I'm happy to delete and start again if something doesn't work as expected, but I also need to be sure that as I progress, any lack of desired result isn't due to my environment.

In this lesson we are required to modify existing code to update the apps single **TextView** using a **Log.d** statement such that we see the **ID division_textview** updated on the phone screen.

I have tried numerous ways to add the final statement

```
findViewById<TextView>(R.id.division_textview).setText("${numerator / denominator}")
```

but cannot add it anywhere such that the values are updated in my emulator. I get no errors but since there is no "solution code" in this lesson, and the lesson's preceding images all serve to rather muddy the picture of exactly how the final code should look, could someone please help me with this?

I really need to be sure my emulator works correctly (there are no errors reported) and that lack of results is my code and not my setup.

This is the lesson in question (thanks for the tip!)

[lesson](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-intro-debugging#5)

Code from my **MainActivity.kt** further to helpful suggestion below. Please note that I realise it's not 'optimal' code, I'm simply attempting to follow instructions at this point.

```
package com.example.debugging

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView

private const val TAG = "MainActivity"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val helloTextView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.division_textview)
        helloTextView.text = "Hello, debugging!"
        logging()
        division()
    }

    fun division() {
        val numerator = 60
        var denominator = 4
        repeat(4) {
            Thread.sleep(3)
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.division_textview).setText("${numerator / denominator}")
            Log.v(TAG, "${numerator / denominator}")
            denominator--
        }
    }

    fun logging() {
            Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: a serious error like an app crash")
            Log.w(TAG, "WARN: warns about the potential for serious errors")
            Log.i(TAG, "INFO: reporting technical information, such as an operation succeeding")
            Log.d(TAG, "DEBUG: reporting technical information useful for debugging")
            Log.v(TAG, "VERBOSE: more verbose than DEBUG logs")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Might help us to link the instructions you're following...

Comment: to be honest, i think even asking for the link might not be so useful, these codelabs could disappear in future, is there a chance you could post all the relevant code here on SO ? i'm assuming this is in an activity, could you post that into your question ?

Comment: I completely concur with @Tenfour04 above, and did indeed note how, inside Android Studio itself it chose to assume my Int value for Thread.sleep would be in milliseconds.

So I've tried manipulating that to values like 3000, but nothing changes.

I've also wondered whether my 'issue' is simply that due to the time it takes to actually recompile the emulator view, the routine has finished.

I'm reluctant to criticize Google or whoever wrote the guides, but  to be honest I've found multiple instances of contradictory or lacking instructions, and I'm barely through the introduction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a very sloppily written and incorrect tutorial. (Yes, even though it's from Google.) If you sleep in the main thread, you're not going to see the text view content change until the entire `repeat` loop is done, so you will only see the final value, after `denominator` has already been decremented to 0. Also, the tutorial claims you will see it change every three seconds even though the code with `Thread.sleep(3)` would only pause for 3 *milli*seconds. And then in their actual example, they used `Thread.sleep(1)`, which contradicts their instructions.

Try this code instead:

```
// added to imports:
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

// modified division function
fun division() = lifecycleScope.launch {
    val numerator = 60
    var denominator = 4
    repeat(4) {
        delay(3000)
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.division_textview).setText("${numerator / denominator}")
        Log.v(TAG, "${numerator / denominator}")
        denominator--
    }
}
```

Using `= lifecycleScope.launch {` turns your function into a coroutine which lets you use the `delay()` function instead of `Thread.sleep()`, so the main thread is given the opportunity to actually update your text view instead of having to wait for the whole `repeat` loop to finish.

---

Here's an alternate way to do it without coroutines, but it's not as pretty:

```
fun division() = with(Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())) {
    val numerator = 60
    var denominator = 4
    repeat(4) { i ->
        postDelayed({
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.division_textview).setText("${numerator / denominator}")
            Log.v(TAG, "${numerator / denominator}")
            denominator--
        }, i * 3000L)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this! Howver, I note that when adding your edits, and while I understand the sense of what they're supposed to achieve, my instance of Android Studio complains about both imports, stating that they're "unresolved reference".

So presumably there's something else amiss with  my overall configuration? I am using recommended settings e.g. API 31, and a Pixel 5... and as far as I can tell (very new to all of this) I have the correct SDK installed, just checked "sync" etc.

A bit stuck as to next steps necessary.

Comment: In your project build.gradle, add this inside plugins: `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false`. In your module build.gradle's `dependencies` section, find the line that mentions android.core and replace it with `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'`. Or just add that line if there isn't an android.core entry already.

Comment: both of these configuration options are already set!

The two terms it specifically doesn't like are "lifecycleScope" and "kotlinx"

Comment: Just to be sure, it says `core-ktx` and not just `core`?

Comment: yes, it's set to the exact text you suggested.

Comment: maybe I was looking for this?

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines

Comment: Yeah, try those. I'm at a loss for what the problem could be. If you create a new project with a recent version of Android Studio, typically coroutines just work out of the box. That site has a more comprehensive list of the dependencies you need, but I thought the appcompat one in combination with core-ktx already includes them as transitive dependencies (ones that get loaded automatically when they're loaded because they depend on them). Like in the project I'm looking at, I don't have `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` specified but it's loaded. I might have missed something, though.

Comment: You can check which dependencies are loaded (including all the transitive ones) by switching the Android drop down in the top left corner to Project and then expanding External Dependencies. By the way, I just added a different way to do this without coroutines in case you just want to try that.

Comment: Thank you for your later solution, this one works exactly as expected/intended.

I suspect that some of my issues re imports is packaging related. I prefer my package manager to install stuff, so I avoided manually installing Android Studio from the .zip bundle. I may have missed other included deps. Nevermind, all is now working and fine. Most importantly I understand it wasn't entirely "me" but was code :D

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I was also surprised by the incorrect code in this tutorial.

I just want to add that, in order to get Studio to know about the lifecycle imports, I had to add the following to gradle.build:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0"
}
```

Which I got from https://github.com/elye/demo_android_compose_state_flow_livedata_viewmodel/blob/main/app/build.gradle